# UIButton doesn't change its size based on the length of the text

Tags: swift, uibutton, storyboard

If I change the type to `plain`, everything works, but it's not a good button type for what I need to do. If I keep it the `default` type the text pops out and the button stays the same size. Do you have any solution?

I also tried to fix it via code, using `button.sizeToFit()` but nothing happens.

I brought all the buttons back to "plain" mode and now everything works, except for the titleColor change of the button corresponding to the correct answer, which should happen when I press the "check" button, but this doesn't happen instantly anymore. I'm forced to press on the correct answer to make it change color.
[click here to see (I can't embed due to low reputation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjmIf.png)

Check button code

```
@IBAction func checkButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if i == 0 {
        i = 1
        checkButtonView.isEnabled = false
        if argomentoLabel.text == "Comprensione" {
            if cultGenBrain[domandaNum!].rightAnswer == "A" {
                // if correct answer is A
                rispostaA.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 151/255, green: 207/255, blue: 175/255, alpha: 1.0), for: .normal)
            } else if {
              (rest of the code)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to print the titleColor of the buttons after pressing on checkButton, and indeed it changes, but not in the screen. to make it change on the screen, I also have to click on the button corresponding to the correct answer, but the buttons containing the answers do not contain any code referring to the "touch up inside" event

Comment: A `default` type button cannot be self-sizing with regard to its height in response to multiple lines in its title text. The title is expected to be a single line that doesn't wrap. If the newer configuration-based button works better, why not use it? You've shown no code so it's really quite impossible to help further.

Comment: i use default because in my app there are buttons where the titleColor should change when another button is pressed. everything works only if the buttons are in default. in "plain" it doesn't work and the color only changes if I then press the other button.

Comment: Well, you need to _make_ it work. There is nothing about the `plain` style that would prevent this. Maybe that's what the question should have been about? But I repeat: you have shown _no code at all_. It is impossible to help you.

Comment: i'm new to stackoverflow. should i create a new thread or can i put the code i used to change the titlecolor here?

Comment: I do not know what a "thread" is in this context. If you wish to improve your question, click the Edit link under your question and edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot say `setTitleColor` in connection with a `.plain` style button. The button is *configuration* based; you need to change the button's content configuration.

Comment: What configuration do you recommend I use to make it work?

Comment: I don't "recommend" anything. The button has a `configuration` property. That is how you _configure_ the button. All of the `set...for` methods are off limits (they apply to the older `system` and `custom` styles only).

Comment: I understand. I don't see "custom" among the possible styles. I see it among the possible types but even setting it to custom doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you see it, because you're not going to use it. You're going to use `plain`.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean, I'm sorry. how can I make the button editable from my code, excluding setting the buttons as "default"?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to write your code for you. Did you look at the UIButton `configuration` property?

Comment: you are right, sorry. inspired by what you wrote I solved with button.configuration?.attributedTitle?.foregroundColor = UIColor